# How to calculate the best solution to a linear, homogeneous, over-determined system

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a linear, homogeneous, over-determined system of equations i.e. I want to solve a matrix equation of the form
$$
\underline{\underline{A}}\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}
$$
where $\underline{\underline{A}}$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $\textbf{x}$ is a vector of dimension $n$ containing the unknowns to be determined and $\textbf{0}$ is the zero vector of dimension $m$. The system is over-determined in the sense that $m>n$. In the absence of noise in my data, there would be a solution to the system (which would be unique). However, the noise ensures that there isn't an exact solution to the system.

I would like to know the best way to obtain a solution which is numerically as close as possible to satisfying the system. Admittedly, I'm a little unsure about how best to define what is the best solution here, but I want to provide equal weighting to the $m$ different equations, if possible.

I've been playing around with taking $n$ of the equations and selecting the eigenvector of the corresponding sub-matrix associated with the eigenvalue of smallest magnitude, and then simply averaging these out over different sets of $n$ equations. However, this is a bit fiddly and these seems like quite a fundamental problem in numerical analysis / numerical linear algebra that would likely have a standard approach, which I would be keen to find out about.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One standard way to approach this problem would be to treat it as a linear least squares problem. In this problem, we have a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (with $m\geq n$) and a vector $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, and we seek to minimize

\begin{equation*}
  \lVert A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}  \rVert_{2}  
\end{equation*}

over $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. That is, we want to minimize the two-norm of the residual vector $A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}$.

Yours is, of course, the special case $\mathbf{b} = 0$.

Standard generalizations of this method exist to treat the cases where the data $\mathbf{b}$ are noisy (the *generalized* least squares problem). In this case, we assume that we can write

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{b} = A\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{w}
\end{equation*}

where $\mathbf{w}$ represents the "noise." For example, if the elements of the noise vector are assumed to be distributed with mean $0$ and  standard deviations $\sigma_{i}$, the problem amounts to minimizing over $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the quantity

\begin{equation*}
  \lVert B^{-1}(A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b})  \rVert_{2}
\end{equation*}

where $\sigma^{2} B^{T}B = \sigma^{2}W$ is the (symmetric and positive definite) covariance matrix corresponding to the noise distribution (where $B$ might be some given matrix or it might be the factor in the Cholesky factorization of $W$). This particular formulation ensures that all of the equations defined by $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ contribute equally to the determination of $\mathbf{x}$.

At any rate, many standard references explain in detail the theory and practice of such methods, and I'm happy to provide some! One classic reference with somewhat greater emphasis on the implementation of these methods is Golub and Van Loan's *Matrix Computations*. The 6th chapter of the 4th edition is dedicated to least squares problems.